# Does Pro guard removes airpush?

Tags: android, proguard, ads

So i have a few apps on the app store, when they are in development process like not signed with keys or anything just installing the app via ADB the ads show up just fine. But every since i started using progruard the ads are not showing up anymore. is there a fix for that?
oh and if it helps, I'm using Eclipse not Andro Studio

Comment: yes, are you getting class def not found exception ?

Comment: yes. how to fix that?

Comment: search proguard rules for airpush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the proguard settings they have [on the documentation](http://docs.airpush.com/index.php?title=Android_In-App_SDK_6.0_Documentation)

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:


-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service 
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver 
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider  
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep class com.bugsense.trace.models.** { *; }


-keepclassmembers class **.SmartWallActivity$AppWall$JavaScriptInterface 
 {
   *;
 }

 -keepclassmembers class **.MraidView$JavaScriptInterface 
 {
   *;
 }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * 
 {
    native <methods>;
 }

 -keepclasseswithmembers class * 
  {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  }

 -keepclasseswithmembers class * 
  {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  }

  -keepclassmembers enum * 
  {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
  }

  -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable 
   {
     public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
   }

   -keepclasseswithmembers class **.R$** 
   {
    public static <fields>;
   }

   -keep class * extends android.view.View 
    { 

      public <init>(android.content.Context); 
      public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
      public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
      void set*(***);
       *** get*();
    }

   -keepclassmembers class * 
    {
        static final %                *;
        static final java.lang.String *;
    }


    -keepattributes SetJavaScriptEnabled
    -keepattributes JavascriptInterface
    -keepattributes InlinedApi

    -dontwarn com.bugsense.trace.models.**
```